# Gatsby test error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: testing, jestjs, gatsby

Whenever I try to run jest I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

**This is the code under test:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

import api from '../../api';
import TextInput from '@components/common/forms/TextInput';
import Checkbox from '@components/common/forms/Checkbox';
import CheckboxGroup from '@components/common/forms/CheckboxGroup';
import styles from './profile.module.css';
import commonStyles from '@components/common/common.module.css';
import ForgotPassword from '../ForgotPassword';
import Modal from '@components/Modal/Modal';

const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, "C'mon, your first name is longer than that")
      .required('First name is required'),
    lastName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, "C'mon, your last name is longer than that")
      .required('Last name is required'),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Invalid email address')
      .required('Email is required'),
    currentPassword: Yup.string(),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(8, 'Password has to be at least 8 characters!')
      .matches(
        /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\\^&\\*])/,
        'Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and 1 special character'
      ),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string().oneOf(
      [Yup.ref('password'), null],
      'Passwords must match'
    ),
  }),
  handleSubmit: (payload, { setSubmitting, setErrors, props }) => {
    const user = props.user || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).user;
    api
      .put(`/users/${user._id || user.userId}`, payload, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then(res => {
        toast.success('Your user profile was updated successfully', {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          hideProgressBar: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        toast.error('Something went wrong', {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          hideProgressBar: true,
        });
      });
    setSubmitting(false);
  },
  mapPropsToValues: ({ user }) => ({
    ...user,
  }),
  displayName: 'ProfileForm',
});

class Profile extends Component {
  modalProps = {
    triggerText: 'Forgot Password?',
  };

  modalContent = <ForgotPassword user={{ email: '' }} {...this.props} />;

  render() {
    document.title = 'User Profile';
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      isSubmitting,
      isAdmin,
      setFieldValue,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextInput
            id="firstName"
            type="text"
            label="First Name"
            error={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
            value={values.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="lastName"
            type="text"
            label="Last Name"
            error={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="email"
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            autoComplete="username email"
            error={touched.email && errors.email}
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="currentPassword"
            type="password"
            label="Current Password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            error={touched.currentPassword && errors.currentPassword}
            value={values.currentPassword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <div className={styles.forgotPassword}>
            <Modal
              modalProps={this.modalProps}
              modalContent={this.modalContent}
              modalButtonClassName={commonStyles.modalLinkButton}
              {...this.props}
            />
          </div>
          <TextInput
            id="password"
            type="password"
            label="New Password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            error={touched.password && errors.password}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="confirmPassword"
            type="password"
            label="Confirm Password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            error={touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword}
            value={values.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          {isAdmin && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <h3>Roles</h3>
              <CheckboxGroup
                id="roles"
                className={styles.roles}
                label="Which of these?"
                value={values.roles}
                onChange={setFieldValue}
              >
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="admin"
                  label="Admin"
                  value="admin"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('admin')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="user"
                  label="User"
                  value="user"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('user')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="family"
                  label="Family"
                  value="family"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('family')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="friend"
                  label="Friend"
                  value="friend"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('friend')}
                />
              </CheckboxGroup>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default formikEnhancer(Profile);
```

**This is the test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Profile from '../Profile/Profile';

describe('Profile', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Profile />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The test output complains about the line (with a carret pointing at create):

```
const tree = renderer.create(<Profile />).toJSON();
```

What might I be doing wrong here to get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5268

Essentially, you need to have the exact same versions of react, react-dom, and react-test-renderer in your devDependencies to avoid this error.